# Cant manipulate global/local variables inside a function in R

Tags: r

```
dna = c("A","G","C","T")

x =sample(dna,50,replace =TRUE)


dna_f = function(x){
  dnastring <- ""
  for (val in x){
    paste(dnastring,val,sep="")
      
  }
  return(dnastring)
  
}
dna_f(x)
```

I'm trying to produce a single string that contains all the randomly sampled letters. x contains all 50 letters and im trying to combine them into one string using the paste function. but when i run this, the output is an empty string. I tried placing dnastring as a global variable because i thought maybe the scope of a function operates differently in R(I'm new to R) but i got the same output. some help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `dnastring <-`

```
dna = c("A","G","C","T")

x =sample(dna,50,replace =TRUE)


dna_f = function(x){
  dnastring <- ""
  for (val in x){
    dnastring <- paste(dnastring,val,sep="")
    
  }
  return(dnastring)
  
}
```

Output:

```
> dna_f(x)
[1] "GGTCTGGCCGAACTACTGTACACCCCAAAGACAACGCCCCCGACGCTCTA"
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `for` loop here. Try `paste` with `collapse` argument.

```
dna_f = function(x){
  paste0(x, collapse = '')
}

dna_f(x)
#[1] "CCTACCAACCCTTTCTAGCCCACTATGCATCACAACTGCGGTCTCATCAC"
```